# NullPointerException in JxBrowser when passing null from JavaScript to Java

Tags: javascript, java, nullpointerexception, jxbrowser

The following code causes a NullPointerException within the JxBrowser (Version 6.14) java code which i can not debug any further, when passing `null` as argument to a java-method.

In the documentation it says `null` converts to `null`, so i assume it should work and it's a bug: https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013062-calling-java-from-javascript (table at the bottom)

Any ideas how to "fix" this?

```
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.BrowserPreferences;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.JSObject;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.LoggerProvider;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.events.ConsoleEvent;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.events.ConsoleListener;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.events.ScriptContextEvent;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.events.ScriptContextListener;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.BrowserView;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class SSCCE_JxBrowser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LoggerProvider.setLevel(Level.INFO); // ALL
        BrowserPreferences.setChromiumSwitches("--remote-debugging-port=9222");

        Browser browser = new Browser();
        BrowserView browserView = new BrowserView(browser);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(browserView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(700, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setTitle("JxBrowser Test");
        frame.setVisible(true);

        browser.addScriptContextListener(new ScriptContextListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScriptContextDestroyed(ScriptContextEvent event) {}

            @Override
            public void onScriptContextCreated(ScriptContextEvent event) {
                JSObject window = event.getBrowser().executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("window").asObject();
                window.setProperty("java", new JavaObject());
            }

        });

        browser.addConsoleListener(new ConsoleListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMessage(ConsoleEvent event) {
                System.out.println("log: " + event);
            }

        });

        browser.loadHTML("<html><head>" //
                + "<script>" //
                + "java.log('Ok!');" // this is OK
                + "java.log(null);" // this fails with NullPointerException
                + "</script>" //
                + "<body>page loaded - <a href=\"" + browser.getRemoteDebuggingURL() + "\" target=_blank>debug</a>"
                + "</body></html>");
    }

    public static class JavaObject {

        public void log(String msg) {
            System.out.println("msg: " + msg);
        }

    }

}
```

- **Output (html):**

  - `Uncaught java.lang.NullPointerException: null`
- **Output (java):**

  - `msg: Ok!`
  - `log: ConsoleEvent{lineNumber=1, message='Uncaught java.lang.NullPointerException: null', source='about:blank'}`

Using an **exception breakpoint** i found this stacktrace:

```
Thread [IPC Sync Events Thread] (Suspended (exception java.lang.NullPointerException))  
    com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.JSContext.a(com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.JSContext, com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.message.OnInvokeJSJavaMessage) line: 2608  
    com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.JSContext$a.onMessageReceived(com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.message.Message) line: 280 
    com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.p.a(com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.p, com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.message.Message) line: 1082  
    com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.q.run() line: 66    
    com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.q.run() line: 63    
    java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter<T>.call() line: 511  
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask<V>.run() line: 266  
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: 1142    
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 617  
    java.lang.Thread.run() line: 748
```

Comment: did you consider not passing `null`?

Comment: `"java.log(null);" // this fails with NullPointerException` of course... you're passing null...

Comment: I want to pass `null` to my java object. `NullPointerException` should only happen when trying to do something like `null.method()`. Plus the documentation says, that `null` converts to `null`, so it seems to be supported. Plus again: The JFX browser (which is an alternative to JxBrowser) does support passing `null` to java. Passing `null` within JS code method calls is also no problem. I believe this is a bug.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I am trying to replace JFX Browser with JxBrowser. We have a lot of legacy and foreign code that passes `null` in this manner in many places. So not passing `null` is not an option. The only option would be to escape it and unescape it on the java side. But this is again problematic since the same JS code also runs against other host-implementations (Android & HTML), which then need the unescaping code as well; or we need a switch so we only escape for the JxBrowser host application.

Comment: Which version of JxBrowser do you use?

Comment: @G.Fiedler Using version `6.14` (currently the newest)

Comment: It looks like an issue in JxBrowser. I have reported this issue to JxBrowser team. The issue will be fixed in one of the next versions. Meanwhile I recommend that you avoid passing null as argument to the injected Java object methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in JxBrowser 6.19.2-b1-eap build available for [download](https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/eap/jxbrowser-6.19.2-b1-eap-cross-desktop-win_mac_linux.zip). The fix will be included into the next official release.

Answer (score 1):

You are welcome to download JxBrowser 6.20 with the fix included.